# How to Implement a custom authentication attribute in Blaozr WASM

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I ran into a scenario where i needed to customize the identity role system
Here I created another table named `Projects` and connected it to the `UserRoles` table, my roles are such that a user can have a role within a project, which means that apart from the user and the role, have another key that must be checked.
For this purpose, I customized `Authorize` attribute on the Asp.net Api project side as below

```
public class AuthAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string[] Roles { get; init; }
    public AuthAttribute(params string[] roles) => Roles = roles;

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context,ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if(!context.HttpContext.User.Identity!.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }
        int projectId = int.Parse(context.HttpContext.GetHeaderValue("ProjectId"));
        var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUserManagerService>();
        int userId = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetId();
        foreach(var role in Roles)
        {
            var isHasRole = await userManager!.IsInRolAsync(userId,role,projectId);
            if(isHasRole)
                return;
        }
        context.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }
}
```

> I use JWT authentication and get the project name from header

I use the roles and projects on the client side as an array using the following model inside the JWT claims

```
public class RoleProjectClaimModel
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Also, project id should be checked, it is local storage saved

**How can i customize the authentication attribute in Blazor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a custom authorization policy for it. This is how you can do it:

First you should define a custom `Requirement` and `Handler`. Inside the handler you have access to the info of the logged-in user such as its claims and roles, etc:

```
public class UserCanSeeProjectRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public UserCanSeeProjectRequirement() { }

}


public class UserCanSeeProjectHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserCanSeeProjectRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
                                                   UserCanSeeProjectRequirement requirement)
    {
        //claim-based validation
        if (context.User.HasClaim("permission.cansee", "CanSee"))
                context.Succeed(requirement);

        //role-based validation
        if (context.User.IsInRole("admin") || context.User.IsInRole("user"))
                context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then introduce them to your client app, this way:

```
namespace BlazorWasm.Client
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ...

            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, UserCanSeeProjectHandler>();
            services.AddAuthorizationCore(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("UserCanSeeProjectPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserCanSeeProjectRequirement()));
            });

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This new custom policy is called `UserCanSeeProjectPolicy`. Now you can use it at the top of a page using `@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "UserCanSeeProjectPolicy")]` or you can use it in an `AuthorizeView`:

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="UserCanSeeProjectPolicy">
    <NotAuthorized>
       <h2 class="mt-5">You are not authorized to view this page</h2>
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorized>
      <div class="container my-profile">
        --- Place here all the content you want your user to view ----
      </div>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```